# Quarto: is there any way to create an "other format" tab for pdf without Quarto rendering it?

Tags: quarto

On my Quarto website I have a CV page, with the content also available in docx and pdf other formats (new feature of Quarto 1.3)

I wanted the pdf and docx to be identical, so I use a post-render python script to overwrite the LaTeX pdf with one created via MS Word from the docx output

This works just fine, but I wondered for the sake of speed, would there be a way of not rendering the LaTeX version of the pdf in the first place, but still have it appear as an alternate format?

For reference, here is the web page in question: https://capaldi.info/cv